# Учет кликов на рекламный баннер в процессе перехода из приложения в браузер по рекламной ссылке

Tags: java

Необходимо сделать учет кликов на рекламный баннер (AdMob) в процессе перехода из приложения в браузер по рекламной ссылке. Добавляю слушатель AdListener() и приложение закрывается, выдает ошибку. Уже 2-а дня убил на эту проблему, на форумах ничего подобного не нашел.

До добавления слушателя рекламный баннер работает, реклама выводиться в приложении
Установил в SDK последнюю версию google-play-services_lib.

Прописал в Манифесте:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    package="com.bss.sm"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"  />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"  />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme" >

            <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.bss.sm.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="SelectionActivity"></activity>

        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

activity_selection.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_adMod"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <com.google.ads.AdView
                android:id="@+id/adView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                ads:adSize="BANNER"
                ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_publisher_id"
                ads:loadAdOnCreate="true">
            </com.google.ads.AdView>

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" >
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>

</LinearLayout>

import com.google.android.gms.ads.*;
public class SelectionActivity extends TabActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_selection);

adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
        adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
              @Override
              public void onAdLeftApplication() {

              }
    });
    }
}
```

Логи:

```
07-29 23:24:45.103: I/Ads(13187): To get test ads on this device, call adRequest.addTestDevice("23822F6685086600AD72B530FDB6314A");

07-29 23:24:45.523: D/AndroidRuntime(13187): Shutting down VM
07-29 23:24:45.523: W/dalvikvm(13187): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40fc72a0)
07-29 23:24:45.573: E/AndroidRuntime(13187): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-29 23:24:45.573: E/AndroidRuntime(13187): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.bsidorenko.smski.SelectionActivity$2
07-29 23:24:45.573: E/AndroidRuntime(13187):    at com.bsidorenko.smski.SelectionActivity.startSelectionActivity(SelectionActivity.java:135)
07-29 23:24:45.573: E/AndroidRuntime(13187):    at com.bsidorenko.smski.SelectionActivity.onCreate(SelectionActivity.java:122)
07-29 23:24:45.573: E/AndroidRuntime(13187):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5047)
07-29 23:24:45.573: E/AndroidRuntime(13187):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
07-29 23:24:45.573: E/AndroidRuntime(13187):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2056)
07-29 23:24:45.573: E/AndroidRuntime(13187):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117)
07-29 23:24:45.573: E/AndroidRuntime(13187):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134)
07-29 23:24:45.573: E/AndroidRuntime(13187):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218)
07-29 23:24:45.573: E/AndroidRuntime(13187):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-29 23:24:45.573: E/AndroidRuntime(13187):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-29 23:24:45.573: E/AndroidRuntime(13187):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
07-29 23:24:45.573: E/AndroidRuntime(13187):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-29 23:24:45.573: E/AndroidRuntime(13187):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-29 23:24:45.573: E/AndroidRuntime(13187):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
07-29 23:24:45.573: E/AndroidRuntime(13187):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
07-29 23:24:45.573: E/AndroidRuntime(13187):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Выложите, пожалуйста, лог ошибки.

Comment: @sba-bgtu, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: Добавил логи в основной вопрос